# How can we reset a radio button after some other radio buttons in the same group have been selected

Tags: html, angular, typescript, radio-button

I have a list of values that are to be displayed as Radio buttons. Each radio button has a value with certain count that will be decreased if the radio button is selected. If radioButton1 is selected then the count becomes 1, if some other radio button say radioButton2 in this list is selected then the count of the radioButton1 is restored to its original value and the count for the radionButton2 is decreased by one. I have been trying to find a solution to this but haven't been able to. Any help will be greatly appreciated thanks!

app.component.ts

```
this.itemList = [

{ name: 'item1', count: 1},
{ name: 'item2', count: 2},
{ name: 'item3', count: 3},
{ name: 'item4', count: 2},
{ name: 'item5', count: 1},
]

onRadioSelect(userSelect){

this.itemList.forEach((selected,index)=>{
        if(selected.name === userSelect.value){
          
            selected.count -= 1;
      
            if(selected.count === 0){
              this.countZeroDisable= index;
            }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let items of itemList; let idx = index" [ngClass]="{'disable': idx===countZeroDisable}">
          <input type="radio" name="List1" [value]="items.name" [disabled]="idx===countZeroDisable" (change)= onRadioSelect(List1) #List1>
             {{items.name}}({{items.count}})
          </div>
```

Comment: So in short, which ever option is selected then the count for that object should be reduced by 1 and the rest should be restored?

Comment: Also, the code you shared doesn't even compile. Please share a minimal, verifiable example.

Comment: yes exactly! restored to the original count

Comment: I have made a few corrections in my code , sorry about that. https://plnkr.co/edit/zCNfHAqjocjLmwUg?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1&preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the following change:

.ts

```
  onRadioSelect(userSelect) {
    this.itemList.forEach(e => {
      if (e['selected']) {
        e.count = e.count + 1;
        e['selected'] = false;
      }
      if (e.name === userSelect.value) {
        e.count -= 1;
        e['selected'] = true;
      }
    })
  }
```

.html

```
<div *ngFor="let items of itemList">
    <input type="radio" name="List1" [value]="items.name" [disabled]="items.count === 0"
        (change)=onRadioSelect(List1) #List1>
    {{items.name}}({{items.count}})
</div>
```

To simplify things, a new field called *selected* is added to determine which is the index currently selected. If the index was previously selected then the count is reset else the count is incremented.

Answer (score 0):

In `app.component.html`

Change the method

```
onRadioSelect(List1)
```

to

```
onRadioSelect(items)
```

So you can take the selected item form `onRadioSelect`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use FormControl and angular handle this for you
try to use ReactiveFormModule and other parts of form in angular.
it's easy to use and very helpful.